# Theano gradient of sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, theano

I'm trying to implement an autoencoder with sparse inputs in Theano.

I got the sparse autoencoder to work with a squared error cost function. But if I want to apply a cross-entropy error, which contains matrix multiplications, I get the following error:

```
AsTensorError: ('Variable type field must be a TensorType.', SparseVariable{csr,float64}, Sparse[float64, csr])
```

I uploaded an example notebook illustrating the problem at http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/peterroelants/4946cdbf189c5e75f2b7/raw/2ee7d3e533a4a6ac2707a2ffa310b81a86e70afd/gistfile1.json .

I distilled the problem down to the matrix multiplication `cost = T.sum(x * T.log(z))`. This works in the dense case [see cell 2], but gives an error in the sparse case [see cell 3]. Note that changing this cost function in the sparse case [cell 3] to the squared error (`cost = T.sum((x-z)**2)`) will result in a working result.

Can anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong? And show me how to get a sparse input autoencoder with cross-entropy error to work in Theano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use T.* function on sparse variable. In this case, you can use:

```
theano.sparse.sp_sum((x * T.log(z))
```

\edit This diff fix in Theano fix this crash:

```
diff --git a/theano/sparse/basic.py b/theano/sparse/basic.py
index 4620c5a..a352b9a 100644
--- a/theano/sparse/basic.py
+++ b/theano/sparse/basic.py
@@ -2244,7 +2244,7 @@ class MulSD(gof.op.Op):
     def grad(self, (x, y), (gz,)):
         assert _is_sparse_variable(x) and _is_dense_variable(y)
         assert _is_sparse_variable(gz)
-        return y * gz, x * gz
+        return y * gz, dense_from_sparse(x * gz)

     def infer_shape(self, node, shapes):
         return [shapes[0]]
```

I'll try to get the fix merged in Theano this week.

Comment: If I change `cost = T.sum(x * T.log(z))` to `cost = theano.sparse.sp_sum(x * T.log(z))` then I still get the following error: `AsTensorError: ('Variable type field must be a TensorType.', SparseVariable{csr,float64}, Sparse[float64, csr])`.

I illustrated this in the following notebook:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/peterroelants/22990100d2c2973e75dc/raw/f30f2921789bd837df8e3021a1c2f6503e1fc6cc/gistfile1.txt

Comment: This was fixed in Theano master. thanks for the report.